# Schedule crawler job with status check & modifiable frequency using backend

Tags: python, cron, scrapy, job-scheduling, fastapi

I want to schedule the execution of a crawler where the frequency will be based on user input in the frontend.
This means, I need to maintain the control of Scrapy execution (`scrapy crawl xbot`) in the backend and change the scheduler frequency accordingly.
And, based on the status of the crawler execution, I will need to run functions to update the database daily.

I've built an MVP using FastAPI, but the scrapy job is currently running independently in a docker container, at a fixed frequency and writing to the DB. The backend, running in a different container, CRUDs the database.

If I use shell scripts to run cron jobs for scrapy command, and python function commands, how do I modify cron job frequency?
If I python scheduler / crontab packages, how do I modify frequency based on user input, and check execution status of the scrapy job?

Any suggestions would be helpful!

ETA: I'm planning to expose the crawler command via API. The backend will contain the scheduler module which will call the API and then synchronously call the dependent background jobs. The other jobs that are not dependent on crawler execution will run independently.
Only issue now is modifying frequency on user input.

Maybe I can restrict it to custom frequencies like "Once at Specific Date & Time" "Every Alternate Day at X time", "Daily at X time", "Every week on Y day at X time",.... and so on, and write specific functions for each. For eg., `schedule.every().day.at(X_time).do(job)`, if...else (7 comparisons) like `if 'thursday': schedule.every().thursday.at(X_time).do(job)`, ...

Comment: Not sure if you can expose an API but if you can, a simple python-flask webserver that exposes an API which modifies the crontab should work out?

Comment: Another solution would be to use https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . It natively supports cron jobs, see https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#cron-jobs ...though I'm not sure if the user is allowed to change the timing of the cron job..

Comment: You would probably be best off using APScheduler (https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)